# Typeinference on Mapentries

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Im trying to understand Typescripts Type-Inference on Records using generics.

In the following i will provide a basic example of what im trying to do

I have the following Type:

```
interface BuildingTypesafeConfiguration<T extends AnyBuilding> {
    typecheck: (building: AnyBuilding) => building is T
    updater: (
        buildingId: Building['id'],
        partialBuilding: Partial<T | DeepReadonly<T>>
    ) => void
}

// Please ignore me im an overcomplicated way of merging types. I post barely any significance to the question
type WrappedInBuildingTypesafeConfiguration<T> = T extends [
    infer HEAD,
    ...infer TAIL
]
    ? HEAD extends AnyBuilding
        ? Record<HEAD['shape'], BuildingTypesafeConfiguration<HEAD>> &
              WrappedInBuildingTypesafeConfiguration<TAIL>
        : never
    : object
```

And the following Object (Record). [Note: "isCuboid", "isCylinder" etc. are typeguards].

```
const buildingUpdateMap: WrappedInBuildingTypesafeConfiguration<
    [CuboidBuilding, CylinderBuilding, PolygonBuilding]
> = {
    [BuildingShape.CUBOID]: {
        typecheck: isCuboid,
        updater: updateCuboidBuilding,
    },
    [BuildingShape.CYLINDER]: {
        typecheck: isCylinder,
        updater: updateCylinderBuilding,
    },
    [BuildingShape.POLYGON]: {
        typecheck: isPolygon,
        updater: updatePolygonBuilding,
    }
}
```

If i now try to bring the map into an invalid state such as the following:

```
const buildingUpdateMap: WrappedInBuildingTypesafeConfiguration<
    [CuboidBuilding]
> = {
    [BuildingShape.CUBOID]: {
        typecheck: isCuboid,
        updater: updateCylinderBuilding, // Error: Types are incompatible
    },
}
```

Typescript correctly inferes that for a cuboid the correct updater must be given. So far so good.
When i use the map in a function as follows:

```
const config = buildingUpdateMap[building.shape]
if (config.typecheck(building)) {
   config.updater(building.id, building) // Argument of type 'CuboidBuilding | CylinderBuilding | PolygonBuilding' is not assignable to parameter of type
}
```

Typescript cannot infer the correlation between the map-key and its inner functions anymore and throws an error. The error basically says that typescript can only infer that building is one of the three possible buildings and you cant set them to any of the updaters, since they expect a specific building.

Why can typescript infer the correlation in the upper map, but not when i use it? Am i missing something?

Comment: Please provide a plaintext [mre] others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  Among other things, that means any non-native types or values need to be declared (or, ideally, removed unless the question actually depends on them).  Right now this code just gives a bunch of errors, most of which are not what you're asking about. If you provide something that self-evidently demonstrates your issue, then others can actually work on it without just speculating.